# android get text from html hidden form field

Tags: android, html, forms

This is the first time i post here. I have a site that has a hidden input field like this:

```
<form autocomplete="off" id="Form1" action="login.aspx" method="post" name="Form1">
     <input type="hidden" value="" name="__EVENTTARGET">
     <input type="hidden" value="" name="__EVENTARGUMENT">
     <input type="hidden" value="dDwtMTg3MDkxXN199v0w==" name="__VIEWSTATE">
```

i want to be able to get the text from the field with name="__VIEWSTATE" and store it into a variable.
All this need to be performed in java for an android app.
Is there any way to get this value from the html code?? I checked the GET method by the site doesn't transmit the value through this. The problem is that this value changes from time to time and i have to get the new value every time.

Comment: Why are you setting the names with PostBack info? Its my understanding event handles are for event tags. The name tag is the ID of the post variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this (hopping your HTML code is well formed...):

```
Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(params[0]);
final NodeList inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(int index = 0; index <inputs.getLength(); index++)
{
    if(inputs.item(index).getUserData("name").equals("__VIEWSTATE"))
    {
        final String yourValue = (String) inputs.item(index).getUserData("value");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644551/auto-fill-forms-in-webview-by-javascript-android

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have acquirred the `HTML` code of the page and you want to get the value of a specific field i would recommend to use a `HTML` parser like [this](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) or [this](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/).

On the other hand your task seems to be so simple that the use of external tools are overkill so it might be sufficient to extract the desired value manually:

```
Pattern matchPattern = Pattern.compile("name=\"__EVENTARGUMENT\"> <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"(.*?)\" name=\"__VIEWSTATE\">");
Matcher m = matchPattern.matcher(yourHTMLCode);
m.find();
String res = m.group(1);
// do something with 'res' containing the desired value
```

Comment: I used the jsoup parser but now i face other problems. The code doesn't seem to work.. Can you figure out the problems?
the code is here [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UWdjL0KhTyKVlMmXbXfFLgY8h2OP_wcyqmmkPi5oMZA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Use Jsoup for HTML parsing for java and Android. It makes all the work easy.